# como extraer un xml de una cadena de texto C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Tengo esta cadena pero quiero sacar el puro `XML` INCIANDO DESDE :

`<cfdi:Comprobante>` HASTA `</cfdi:Comprobante>` Solo quiero ese fragmento, para guardar las variables que me regresa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:bisoft="http://b1-soft.com/addenda/estandar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 Certificado="MIIFyDCCA7CgAwIBAgIUMzAwMDEwMDAwMDA0MDAwMDI0NDMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwggErMQ8wDQYDVQQDDAZBQyBVQVQxLjAsBgNVBAoMJVNFUlZJQ0lPIERFIEFETUlOSVNUUkFDSU9OIFRSS
 UJVVEFSSUExGjAYBgNVBAsMEVNBVC1JRVMgQXV0aG9yaXR5MSgwJgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhlvc2Nhci5tYXJ0aW5lekBzYXQuZ29iLm14MR0wGwYDVQQJDBQzcmEgY2VycmFkYSBkZSBjYWRpejEOMAwGA1UEEQwFMDY
 zNzAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAk1YMRkwFwYDVQQIDBBDSVVEQUQgREUgTUVYSUNPMREwDwYDVQQHDAhDT1lPQUNBTjERMA8GA1UELRMIMi41LjQuNDUxJTAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQITFnJlc3BvbnNhYmxlOiBBQ0RNQS1TQVQwH
 hcNMTkwNjE3MjA0MDUxWhcNMjMwNjE3MjA0MDUxWjCB7zEqMCgGA1UEAxMhWEVOT04gSU5EVVNUUklBTCBBUlRJQ0xFUyBTIERFIENWMSowKAYDVQQpEyFYRU5PTiBJTkRVU1RSSUFMIEFSVElDTEVTIFMgREUgQ1YxK
 jAoBgNVBAoTIVhFTk9OIElORFVTVFJJQUwgQVJUSUNMRVMgUyBERSBDVjElMCMGA1UELRMcWElBMTkwMTI4SjYxIC8gS0FITzY0MTEwMUIzOTEeMBwGA1UEBRMVIC8gS0FITzY0MTEwMUhOVExLUzA2MSIwIAYDVQQLE
 xlYZW5vbiBJbmR1c3RyaWFsIEFydGljbGVzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiJQ5YcSgjwsGf29+3go7VGdtMZCcH9wUpn46ZMAlFwUojnCPTvwJ3+cSwjqJnw8ahr3DuRwekvGR4BJAb5b9X
 i8kyoiWtwcGOSWxO38Bp9J1e/BO9HMbQBPAtLDuG47oqnH8zWLOeaoYRJDpARw4RX1ko2+9tbj0ntBtM7Vk1E8EWiA/h2Meq0LIv1+ySGTUrEW46FM01J5pzELv5XupBghuJxR5DG9fiOW7u3dR5s3tZoVLwA1KdjJtY0
 mmnfCwxg6i5AqhvY+FAI5D6CF6/lHA8PWg63WasvrhuIv70xCLjgPT/j00ZcPrLvBf1DefGVic980Ch/SDvC+MdJ1F5wIDAQABox0wGzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIGwDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgE
 ACjfTPoKY2N5MxjmAMltd5XZCV1vgAwEtrIRYTodhE8R0Tp1QanAXb0luPyBv5hIXWK4VqAI4fcTtP+n7kkrwfha6ErkPWFNJWJm8ZsMmby/3WgVoJkOFyRYQqr5Il3N6wMa5kiDBtDRbqB3iEXmvtrvjWSHyxAER+zo3
 jWGFlhBZ0nQNRtjx8sPFihVc5TUH682HJiU4oWvT63Dnra8ncqiW/uCuY86crnUq0fW7Lw/3+PY5xXjNxR/Hh3sUPITfJrGaLWurD1J9npr9yGAJ6t9zrhhZnepIC0DUMc5+j4pg1DrO32jzwUOLQqErDizh84NoJCW
 wbg+US8wi3zD0ZKiDv7XsTNWAW2Ap2JkzykKHjFTZiEm3uZOkJNfcu3o+kefr5HfXFT+iN9K5FUEhaQwgUeZBRJ8V5F6gmhz3d6ixVbiZoFNhYR8e2k8gF9gGrVMrEbJGQrl+6+ZYQLFiauXeG7fu1svk19PuyredRJG
 nseJqyV4RzcRGhJA+cLnmpdDOTEhignnvnhEuY6HVRYYXhOTyeeluET7KRCxbJGqO7TdWgjrHL3HRbNE4NY5GAdOZuLaWxElG5ZVCHqtG0Nh7UQAhcz+EKyZBAewv5XuH0OomZXw6mM2mY2soL6z1224NusM8/BbJcYTQ
 UlAEKblEChhGK1XlxiVOU2nc9KE=" Fecha="2021-04-08T00:00:00" Folio="8" LugarExpedicion="97196" Moneda="MXN" NoCertificado="30001000000400002443" Sello="RPdhBiQ3Vi4V4DZa
 4tD6JDHMH1DSmeyhTZxq0oeuD9IDQ7KGMsoQNmKRW8zLVqGIgNvDNrq43YlAZ0sEuOLR2DOE3xWOia+9ERGAxK7iwxrusR7XYQcSKWNa65/GTYpzRAE9y84JjRo3LNFCxA20+MoUAptr52ecusR59j+AZOpg0Gw22yu7g
 Z5FOGI476jJbobgDHGbShkYtUqhu/qfPnwkitHMNzwDt7do/1bTXkxIG5EnSAZYwzMoubG4LpLWqY4Bn23tiybmDezuqZePAIq6yS1AlrMSMhQRqbw9AP3dXsyqVADpllk0DLK/DK60XmLLSR+8ma1S2pRtsAweLg==" 
 SubTotal="0.00" TipoCambio="1" TipoDeComprobante="T" Total="0.00" Version="3.3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd 
 http://b1-soft.com/addenda/estandar http://www.b1-soft.com/addenda/estandar/b1estandar.xsd"><cfdi:Emisor Nombre="IQFRESH TRANSPORT 5" RegimenFiscal="601" Rfc="XIA190128J61"/>
 <cfdi:Receptor Nombre="Combustibles de Chazumba" Rfc="AID031212SN4" UsoCFDI="G01"/><cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Concepto Cantidad="500" ClaveProdServ="10101502" ClaveUnidad="31"
 Descripcion="Perros" Importe="5.00" Unidad="Pescar" ValorUnitario="0.01"/></cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Complemento><tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/timbrefiscaldigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1"
 UUID="A66B584C-A666-4ED8-B8E7-026A5FADBBEE" FechaTimbrado="2021-04-09T18:38:49" RfcProvCertif="STB080508AAA" SelloCFD="RPdhBiQ3Vi4V4DZa4tD6JDHMH1DSmeyhTZxq0oeu
 D9IDQ7KGMsoQNmKRW8zLVqGIgNvDNrq43YlAZ0sEuOLR2DOE3xWOia+9ERGAxK7iwxrusR7XYQcSKWNa65/GTYpzRAE9y84JjRo3LNFCxA20+MoUAptr52ecusR59j+AZOpg0Gw22yu7gZ5FOGI476jJbobgDHGb
 ShkYtUqhu/qfPnwkitHMNzwDt7do/1bTXkxIG5EnSAZYwzMoubG4LpLWqY4Bn23tiybmDezuqZePAIq6yS1AlrMSMhQRqbw9AP3dXsyqVADpllk0DLK/DK60XmLLSR+8ma1S2pRtsAweLg==" SelloSAT="CJ9ph
 RbdNORIH5iwbTRNij8w94Q60R9jOy4MsXltkBuheT5xyqwrPxQjMBeK5bwCbT0jfl5dDdVH14r0fsSCA+bOMhQ0xKwck1c6x6crzeCIrtaXVN9c1Lm4yGd/C2jJplnOfVy7cmxYQkEshhlxKNksFcRB8eqZX8h8O8
 yhQE2NGR5RfHCqgEsvhwxLuOYxPivFFKLIZEBBXn2MpycAROYf6O8a5vNAnAwQqMWRY0DqmW4d/XGKcch+uL0RKweUF+3YjOtNPv3POI08SJMNKPs8QkIT2S3hrAY2dWMB8mXJ5yD1RMhOplJyn+YfIsLTlz7gT5L
 jd3DCFWZoVFDe5A==" NoCertificadoSAT="30001000000400002495" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
 </cfdi:Complemento><cfdi:Addenda><bisoft:Estandar><bisoft:ETDUPLI><bisoft:DUPLI IdSucursal="10073" 
 NombreDocumento="cfdi_09042021T183103.xml"/></bisoft:ETDUPLI></bisoft:Estandar></cfdi:Addenda></cfdi:Comprobante>|&acuse|Acuse disponible solo en el ge
 stor de documentos|acuse&|AVISO:FIN AVISO>|<pdf><nombrePDF>cfdi_09042021T183103.xml.pdf</nombrePDF> <mymeTypePDF>UTF-8</mymeTypePDF><base64PDF>JVBERi0xLj</base64PDF> QKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZVJHQi9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlL0hlaWdodCA3OS9GaWx0ZXIvRENURGVjb2RlL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9XaWR0aCAyMTIvQml0c1BlckNvbXB
```

alguna función para quitar el texto a la derecha después de la etiqueta: `</cfdi:Complemento>`

Comment: Agrega el codigo que hayas intentado hasta el momento, y en donde tienes problemas

Comment: no he generado el código aun, soy nuevo en la programación C#. :(

Comment: investiga un poco sobre xml a c# e intenta primero con un objeto xml sencillo de dos propiedades. Cualquier problema agregalo al foro junto con el codigo que lleves al momento.

Comment: si pero yo quiero trasformar esa cadena a un xml la funcion de recorrer las etiquitas ya las tengo pero al momento de trasformar mi texto a xml, por las cadenas que tiene me dice formato invalido por eso quiero borrar las paralabras despues de la etiqueta :</cfdi:Comprobante>

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene algo que ver con la otra que te respondieron?

Comment: si ya me respondieron mi pregunta la elimino para no crear confusion gracias

Comment: @DavidCabrera esta pregunta es un poco diferente, aquí deseas obtener lo que se encuentre entre 2 cadenas, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una forma de obtener la información entre dos cadenas de caracteres, usando `Substring()`,ejemplo :

```
   string firstWord = "<cfdi:Comprobante"; //Cadena izquierda
   string lastWord = "</cfdi:Comprobante>"; //Cadena derecha
    
   string input = "<cfdi:Comprobante abcdefghjklmnñopqrstuvwxyz</cfdi:Comprobante>|&acuse|Acuse disponible solo en el gestor de documentos|acuse&|AVISO:FIN AVISO>|<pdf><nombrePDF>cfdi_09042021T183103.xml.pdf</nombrePDF> <mymeTypePDF>UTF-8</mymeTypePDF><base64PDF>JVBERi0xLj</base64PDF> QKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlL0RldmljZVJHQi9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlL0hlaWdodCA3OS9GaWx0ZXIvRENURGVjb2RlL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9XaWR0aCAyMTIvQml0c1BlckNvbXB";
        
   int start = input.IndexOf(firstWord) + firstWord.Length;
   int end = input.IndexOf(lastWord, start);
   string resultado = input.Substring(start, end - start);
```

El valor obtenido para la variable `resultado` sería:

```
abcdefghjklmnñopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Hola @DavidCabrera  , solo recuerda agregar siempre a tus preguntas lo que trataste o investigaste, no olvides realizar el  [tour] del sitio, saludos.